# Which enchantments allow tapping a creature to inflict direct damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What creatures across all sets and expansions have the ability to inflict direct damage, à la [Prodigal Sorcerer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Prodigal%20Sorcerer)?

Are there any Enchant Creature spells that have target creature gain "Tap to do 1 damage to target creature or player" or something similar?

*Edit: My apologies for such an easily query-able answer. I was not aware of the existence o such comprehensive databases and easily-searchable databases like magiccards.info before posting these questions. I will surely do more research from now on. Thank you!*

Comment: Dude, you need to try researching before using stackexchange as your "query". I believe somewhere here was told that everytime you want to ask, you need to show what you have tried.

Comment: Not to mention that this kind of question is easily queried out of magic card database sites.

Comment: In deed, I was certainly hasty. A combination of excitement of getting back in to the game since 3rd Edition, discovering a community of enthusiasts, and my ignorance of the power of tools available to find such information have resulted in some pretty inane questions on my part in the last two days.  Please accept my apologies, and I will certainly do my best to bring questions that enhance the site rather than pollute it next time!!

Comment: Great attitude. Ill remove the downvote on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few Aura cards that grant creatures the ability to tap to deal damage to a target (some with more restrictions than others). To find these cards, I used the [magiccards.info](http://magiccards.info) search [o:"Enchant Creature" o:"Enchanted creature has" o:deal o:"{T}"](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22Enchant+Creature%22+o%3A%22Enchanted+creature+has%22+o%3Adeal+o%3A%22%7BT%7D%22&v=card&s=cname), which finds Auras that enchant creatures that mention dealing damage and have an ability with a tap cost. Those cards are:

- **[Archery Training](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archery%20Training)**

  > At the beginning of your upkeep, you may put an arrow counter on Archery Training.

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals X damage to target attacking or blocking creature, where X is the number of arrow counters on Archery Training."
- **[Burning Anger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Burning%20Anger)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals damage equal to its power to target creature or player."
- **[Fire Whip](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fire%20Whip)**

  > Enchant creature you control

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals 1 damage to target creature or player."

  > Sacrifice Fire Whip: Fire Whip deals 1 damage to target creature or player.
- **[Hermetic Study](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hermetic%20Study)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals 1 damage to target creature or player."
- **[Hypervolt Grasp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hypervolt%20Grasp)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals 1 damage to target creature or player."

  > {1}{U}: Return Hypervolt Grasp to its owner's hand.
- **[Lavamancer's Skill](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lavamancer%27s%20Skill)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals 1 damage to target creature."

  > As long as enchanted creature is a Wizard, it has "{T}: This creature deals 2 damage to target creature."
- **[Lightning Prowess](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lightning%20Prowess)**

  > Enchanted creature has haste and "{T}: This creature deals 1 damage to target creature or player."
- **[Power of Fire](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Power%20of%20Fire)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals 1 damage to target creature or player."
- **[Predatory Urge](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Predatory%20Urge)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals damage equal to its power to target creature. That creature deals damage equal to its power to this creature."
- **[Psionic Gift](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Psionic%20Gift)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals 1 damage to target creature or player."
- **[Quicksilver Dagger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Quicksilver%20Dagger)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals 1 damage to target player. You draw a card."
- **[Sinstriker's Will](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sinstriker%27s%20Will)**

  > Enchanted creature has "{T}: This creature deals damage equal to its power to target attacking or blocking creature."

Comment: Wow excellent! I paused on Magic around the time 4th Edition was introduced, and I am impressed with the evolution of the game. I have almost come to expect that anything I can conjure up has been done -- looking through what is now probably over 100,000 unique cards seems a little daunting though! Thank you!

Comment: A great resource for finding stuff like this is magiccards.info, which as a great advanced search. I found all of these cards with a search for ['o:"Enchant Creature" o:"Enchanted creature has" o:deal o:"{T}"'](http://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22Enchant+Creature%22+o%3A%22Enchanted+creature+has%22+o%3Adeal+o%3A%22%7BT%7D%22&v=card&s=cname), which searches for cards with the "Enchant Creature" ability that grant that creature an ability that uses the {T} symbol and talk about dealing damage.

Comment: So awesome. I got sucked in to magiccards.info last night for hours. So cool. Thank you for providing this information, as well as your comprehensive answer!

Comment: @murgatroid99: your comment should really be the first part of your answer- it's far more valuable than listing specific cards, and will be helpful far in the future.

Comment: There, I added it.

Comment: OP might also be interested in equipment like Heavy Arbalest. These weren't around back during 4th ed...